# Eclipse + Android SDK errors in code

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-adt

I'm still getting errors in my project. When I edit source files eclipse shows me parenthesis error when there isn't any syntax error. I have to cut code with error and paste it back and than errors disappears. It is very annoying. Is there any way to force eclipse to re validate code?

Comment: have you tried to clean and build again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Project -> Clean`, and see if `Project -> Build Automatically` option is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Goto **Project -> Clean**

this will force eclipse to re validate code again